# Static files not served in Django "dockerized" (dev environnement)

Tags: django, docker-compose, static

EDIT

```
- my_project
    |_app
        |_core
             |_wsqi.py
             |_settings
                 |_base.py   <-- settings.py used for development
                 |_dev.py
                 |_prod.py
             |_urls.py       <-- modifications
        |_requirements
             |_base.txt
             |_dev.txt
             |_prod.txt
        |_Dockerfile
        |_Dockerfile.prod
        |_entrypoint.sh
        |_entrypoint.prod.sh
        |_manage.py
        |_.dockerignore
    |_nginx
    |_.env.dev
    |_.env.prod
    |_.gitignore
    |_docker-compose.yml
    |_docker-compose.prod.yml
```

```
# from django.conf import settings
import core
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('randomization_management/', include('randomization_management.urls')),
    path('randomization_settings/', include('randomization_settings.urls')),   
    path('randomization/', include('randomization.urls')),
    path('export/', include('export.urls')), 
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(core.settings.dev.STATIC_URL, document_root=core.settings.dev.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

I try to "dockerize" a Django apps.

All works fine except static files that are not served.
I use Django web server (dev) so I should not have to "served" static files.

Neverthelsess, I run `docker exec -it coverage_africa_web_1 python manage.py collectstatic` command

and get the confirmation

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination
> location as specified in your settings:
>
> ```
> /usr/src/app/static
> ```
>
> This will overwrite existing files!
> Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
> Found another file with the destination path 'randomization/js/script.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>
> 140 static files copied to '/usr/src/app/static'.

settings.base.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_management/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_settings/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

.env.dev

```
SECRET_KEY=*************************************
DEBUG=1
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=db_dev
SQL_USER=user
SQL_PASSWORD=user
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        restart: always
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./app/:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on: 
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgres/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user
            - POSTGRES_DB=db_dev
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, missing settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")                   <- removed in dev

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),                              <- added in dev
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_management/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_settings/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't use a web server to serve the static files, so make sure that Django is serving the static files.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

have a look to to Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: thanks for replying. As I use Django runserver, it should serve "alone" ; I've update my post with architecture project and modify my urls.py file as recommanded but didn't changed...